# Apply Transform and Rest Pose Not Working After Restart Blender

Tags: modeling, rigging, transforms, scale, pose-mode

I've been working on a character model, and all seems well during a single session. However, after exiting and restarting blender, my model is scaled several thousand times larger than it was when I saved it, and the pose always defaults to this strange pose:

[image]

When it is supposed to look like this:

[image]

I can still use "ALT+G" AND "ALT+R" in pose mode to fix the pose issue, but "ALT+S" does not fix the scale issue. And in object mode, when I try to scale the model and armature back to the original size, the changes are not saved the next time I re-open blender (the pose reverts to the undesired pose as well). Even if I goto "object> apply> Location / Rotation / Scale."

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I determined the cause of the problem! I must have accidentally set a keyframe for the the armature scale and rotation! The strange part is that I never once placed the armature in that strange position, but I checked the graph editor and found keyframes on all joints. Once I deleted the keyframes everything looked good after saving and re-opening blender.

Comment: As mentioned in your question. **Applying** Transforms on the bones, would have actually been very harmful. Good thing you didn't do that.

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose I wasn't totally clear. You're right that it's harmful to apply transforms to bones while in pose mode or edit mode. I was applying the transform in object mode to the entire armature.

Comment: Don't worry, I understood. Just making it extra clear for future readers.